# Creating a hedear menu by extending twig templates

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to achieve menu below but for some reason it doesn't show middle parts (level 2 and 3) of the menu if I navigate up to level 3 and 4. If I'm on level 3 then 1, 2, 3 should be visible. If I'm on level 4 then all the levels. That's what I want to achieve.

I read whole [templating documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913042/how-do-i-extend-a-twig-template-in-the-same-directory-of-my-other-templates) and some more but cannot find why my code below won't work.

Expected:

```
FRONTEND - BACKEND
----------------------
COUNTRY | LEAGUE      -> After selecting FRONTEND in level 1 above
----------------------
INDEX | LIST | CREATE -> After selecting COUNTRY in level 2 above
----------------------
Countries will appear here after selecting LIST in level 3 above
```

My failed attempts:

```
FRONTEND - BACKEND
----------------------
INDEX | LIST | CREATE -> After selecting COUNTRY in level 2 above
----------------------
```

or

```
FRONTEND - BACKEND
----------------------
Countries will appear here after selecting LIST in level 3 above
```

**base.html.twig**

```
   Football
      BackendBundle
      .....
      FrontendBundle
         Resources
            views
               Default
                  index.html.twig
               Country
                  index.html.twig
                  list.html.twig
```

**base.html.twig**

```
<body>
    <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_default_index') }}">FRONTEND</a>
    &nbsp;&dash;&nbsp;
    <a href="{{ path('football_backend_default_index') }}">BACKEND</a>
    <hr />
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

**Default/index.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_index') }}">COUNTRY</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_league_index') }}">LEAGUE</a>
        <hr />
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Country/inedx.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'FootballFrontendBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_index') }}">Index</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_list') }}">List</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_create') }}">create</a>
        <hr />
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Country/list.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'FootballFrontendBundle:Country:index.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% spaceless %}
        COUNTRY - List
        <hr />
        ....
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `body` block in your file `Country/list.html.twig`, you replace the one in the root file `base.html.twig`. It's the same than method inheritance in PHP. If you want to do what you try to achieve, you have two ways :

1. Use {{ parent() }} inside your block, to display the parent template content of the block
2. Use a different name for your blocks for each subtemplate

E.g.

**Default/index.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_index') }}">COUNTRY</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_league_index') }}">LEAGUE</a>
        <hr />
    {% endspaceless %}
    {% block body2 %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Country/inedx.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'FootballFrontendBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}

{% block body2 %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_index') }}">Index</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_list') }}">List</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="{{ path('football_frontend_country_create') }}">create</a>
        <hr />
    {% endspaceless %}
    {% block body3 %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the example. I think I'll use `parent`. +1